# Directional derivative, tangent vector, double integrals

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

> 1. Let f be differentiable on the domain $D$ and let $\nabla f(x_0, y_0) = (0, 0)$. Then every directional derivative of $f$ at $(x_0, y_0)$ is $0$.
> 2. Let $C$ be a parametrized curve with arc-length parameter. Then every tangent vector at every point on $C$ is a unit tangent vector.
> 3. Let $f(x)$ be a continuous odd function and let $g(y,z)$ be a continuous function on a unit sphere $S$. Then $\int\int_S f(x)~g(y,z)~dS =0$.

So I am supposed to figure out which of these are false and which of these are true. I have reviewed the material a few times but I still don't get these statements. Can someone please help me explain the three concepts and help me identify the false statements? Thanks in advance.